# How to combine 'vertical' list and separate them with blank space in 1 'sentence style' line with WORD or EXCEL?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I want to turn this list:

listA
listB
listC
listD
listE

into:

listA listB listC listD listE

in MS Word: I tried using CTRL H> Find (**Manual Line Break**) > Replace with (**space**) but it doesnt work. Any ideas how can i achieve this or to even add something like comma in between them?

edit Tab to Manual Line Break

Comment: Why you search for *tab*? search for newline or soft-linebreak, dependent by what you have...

Comment: thank you for pinpointing. brainfog i thought tabbing would break lines. So i tried manual line break from the list it doesnt work aswell MS Word cant find it.

Comment: Paragraph Mark
Tab Character
Any Character
Any Digit
Any Letter
Caret Character
S Section Character
11 Paragraph Character
Column Break
full Width Ellipsis
Em Dash
1/4 Em Space
En Dash
No-Width Optional Break
No-Width Non Break
Endnote Mark
Footnote Mark
Graphic
Manual Line Break
Manual Page Break
Nonbreaking Hyphen
Nonbreaking Space
Optional Hyphen
Section Break
White Space

Comment: *So i tried manual line break from the list it doesnt work aswell MS Word cant find it* Enable invisible symbols draw and look what symbol does you have in practice.

Comment: PS. In Excel (it is mentioned in subj) you're to use TRANSPOSE() array function.

Comment: Word worked for me. Enabling invisible symbols made me  realize that my list is separated by paragraph brakes!

Answer (score 0):

to turn this list:

listA
listB
listC
listD
listE

into:

listA listB listC listD listE

using MS Word, verify what separates the list by (show all formatting marks) in Display Word Options. I was using paragraph breaks hence:

CTRL H> Find (**Paragraph Mark**) > Replace all with (**Non Breaking space**)